# Wix Merge Module Express a Dependency on .Net 2.0

Tags: .net, wix, windows-installer, installation, wix3.5

I have built a WIX merge module (.wxs) delivering several components to a target machine and am struggling to understand what/who/how is responsible for delivering/installating the dependencies of these components.

Each component is a .NET 2.0 assembly and therefore my merge module requires .NET 2.0 to be installed on the client machine.

How do I express/implement this in my merge module?
1. Do I somehow express a dependecy on .NET 2.0 and consumers of my merge module must ship and install the required framework?
2. Do I add a requirement on a .NET 2.0 merge module and have my merge module install the .NET 2.0 merge module.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Properly authored and compild .NET 2.0 assemblies probably really have a dependency on .NET 2.0, 3.0 or 3.5 ( CLR 2.0 ) or .NET 4.0 / 4.5 (CLR 4.0 ).  So it's probably more accurate to say you need .NET 2.0 or greater.

That said, a merge module is just one piece of the puzzle.  How you choose to design this expression is up to you and here is one way I'd consider doing it.

It's not the merge module's job to install .NET.  In fact, it can't due to a Windows Installr mutex that enforces one execute sequence per machine.  This means it's not the MSI's job either.  This is where bootstrapper and chainers come in.

What the MSI can do though is double check the chainer did it's job.  And this expression can be authored in the MSI or in a merge module.

You start off by authoring an AppSearch / Reglocator to detect .NET.  WiX NetFx extensions have some built in properties you can reference to make this easier.

Now you author the LaunchCondition. However, with WiX the Condition element doesn't exist in a merge module.  This is because MSDN says MergeModules shouldn't use the LaunchCondition table.  Instead you author a Type 19 error custom action and sequence it in the tables.

Now you might wish to put a condition on this check that allows the MSI to override the check. ( Not DOTNETFRAME20FOUND and Not IGNOREDOTNETFRAME20).  In fact you might want to put all of this in a merge module ( REQUIRESDOTNETFRAME20.msm ) and reference it by multiple merge modules that all share the same dependency ( don't repeat yourself ).

At my last job we did product line development which meant thousands of merge modules came together in different combinations to create dozens of products.   We expressed all of this in unique modules and usually created the association at the product layer rather then the service family / component layer.   Sometimes we did if it was an unusual dependency.

Comment: Many thanks for your well thought out and articulated response.